# Probability of rolling higher than $N$ by summing the highest $X$ number of dice out of a set $Y$ number of dice, each with $Z$ sides.

Tags: probability, dice

I'd like help finding a formula for the probability of rolling higher than a target number, $N$, by summing the highest $X$ number of dice out of a set $Y$ number of dice, each with $Z$ sides, numbered $1 \to Z$.

Given (and obvious): $N < X*Z, \:\:X < Y$

Edit #1: For sake of simplicity lets make $Z=6$ and $X=3$

In dice notation it would be $P(Yd6k3>N)$. Thanks to SuperJedi224 for that.

I've tried brute force through an Excel sheet and http://rumkin.com/reference/dnd/diestats.php but the Excel sheet got really cumbersome after 46656 lines ($6d6k3$) and the website bugged out at $8d6k3$.

Edit #2: What would the odds be of each of the possible outcomes on $Y$ dice?

For example, what are the odds that $Y$ dice roll the set (4,5,3)? If that could be figured out for each of the $6^3$ possible outcomes, it would get us really close to an answer for the original question.

Comment: You are looking for `P(YdZkX>N)`, correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm hoping for an answer written as a algebraic expression.

Comment: Sry, I missread the question... you are adding a maximal subset of a throw. An exact answer to this problem seems too complicate, it is far faster just take the probabilities through experimentation (try something better than excel).

Comment: An approach could be to figure out the probability of each possible result of 3 to 18 on $X$ dice

Comment: So I've found an answer to my prior comment and second edit.
The probability, $P$, of getting each of the $6^3$ possible sets of 3 numbers on $Y$ dice is $[1-(5/6)^Y]*[1-(5/6)^{Y-1}]*[1-(5/6)^{Y-2}]$.
Now I just need to find a little time to work out the rest of the math.